# how to create multi-index in logstash whith tags

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have 2 directories and I want each one to be a different index in elasticsearch this is the .conf file

```
input {
  stdin { type => "stdin-type"}
    file{
       path => "/home/falcoroot/development/falco/Jsons/**/*.json"
       add_tag => ["post"]
       start_position => "beginning"
       sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
       ignore_older => 0
    }
    file{
       path => "/home/falcoroot/development/falco/Clasificados/**/*.json"
       add_tag => ["class"]
       start_position => "beginning"
       sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
       ignore_older => 0
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
            codec=>dots
    }
    if "post" in [tags]{
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "localhost"
                    index => "facebook"
                    document_type => "posts"
                    document_id => "%{id}"
            }
    }
    if "class" in [tags]{
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "localhost"
                    index => "clasificados"
                    document_type => "posts"
                    document_id => "%{id}"
            }
    }
```

Please if someone know what I'm doing wrong tell me, or tell me the correct way to create different index whit logstash

Comment: `hosts => "localhost"` should be `hosts => "localhost:9200"`. Also, why not just create two different conf files for individual directories. Why complicate if both are meant to be in different indexes.? You havent mentioned any error too.

Comment: sorry I am new here and new in logstash, I am going to try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a curly bracket missing at the very end, but I guess that's just a copy problem. Instead of using tags why not use type like follows ... also, it is always a good idea to add a variable part like a date to the index name.

Another thing: in elasticsearch think of an "index" as a database and the "type" is like a table. Maybe you want to use the same index, but use different type ?

This config worked for me:

```
input {
  stdin { type => "stdin-type"}
  file{
     path => "/home/falcoroot/development/falco/Jsons/**/*.json"
     type => "facebook"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     ignore_older => 0
 }
 file{
     path => "/home/falcoroot/development/falco/Clasificados/**/*.json"
     type => "clasificados"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     ignore_older => 0
 }
}
output {
  stdout {
        codec=>dots
  }
  if [type] in ["clasificados", "facebook"] {
     elasticsearch {
         hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         index => "%{type}_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
         document_type => "posts"
         document_id => "%{id}"
     }
  }
}
```